# Why is Perl XML::LibXML changing UTF8 to 8859-1?

Tags: xml, perl, utf-8

With this input file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
   <title>ú</title>
</entry>
```

and this code,

```
my $raw_xml = read_file("test.xml", binmode => 'raw');
print "$raw_xml\n";
$raw_xml =~ /<title>(.*?)</;
print "Regex finds [$1]\n";      # prints u+accent to UTF8 terminal

my $dom  = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $raw_xml);
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
my ($entry) = $xpc->findnodes('entry');
my $title = $xpc->findvalue('title', $entry) || '';

print "title is now [$title]\n"; # prints garbage character to UTF8 terminal, u+accent to ISO-8859-1 terminal
```

Where/why is perfectly good utf8 being translated into one of the 8 bit character sets (I'm assuming it's 8859-1, could be cp1252 etc)?

Everything I've found via Google suggests that it should all be utf8 from end to end.  But clearly it's not.

Note: the behaviour is exactly the same if I open the file on a filehandle with binmode and pass it into load_xml; I happen to have the xml in memory in the real code this is distilled from - it also means I can verify with a regex as above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two bugs which cancel out to produce the correct output in the first test.

---

**Your home-grown parser doesn't decode the document**

You can observe this bug by changing `/<title>(.*?)</` to `/<title>(.)</`. Rather than getting the first glyph (`ú`) as intended, it only gets the first byte of its encoding (`C3`).

To fix this, replace

```
$raw_xml =~ /<title>(.*?)</;
print "Regex finds [$1]\n";
```

with

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

my $decoded_xml = decode_utf8($raw_xml);
$decoded_xml =~ /<title>(.*?)</;
print "Regex finds [$1]\n";
```

Now you get the same behaviour from both tests, namely the same garbage output. This brings us to the second problem.

---

**You don't encode your outputs**

XML::LibXML returns decoded text aka Unicode Code points. `ú` is therefore returned as character `FA` since `ú` is U+000FA. This is proper as you shouldn't have to care about encodings except when doing I/O.

The problem happens when doing I/O. `print` expects each character it receives to represent a byte, so when you tell it to print character `FA`, it prints byte `FA`, and your terminal goes "wtf?".

Your terminal expects UTF-8, so you either need to encode the string using `UTF-8` before passing it to `print`, or tell `print` to do it for you.

```
# Decode STDIN (UTF-8).
# Decode STDOUT and STDERR (UTF-8).
# The default encoding for files opened in scope is UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

---

Complete solution:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

my $raw_xml = read_file("test.xml", binmode => 'raw');

{
   my $decoded_xml = decode_utf8($raw_xml);
   my ($title) = $decoded_xml =~ /<title>(.*?)</;
   printf("%s: [%s] [%s]\n", "Home-grown", $title, substr($title, 0, 1));
}

{
   my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $raw_xml );
   my ($entry_node) = $doc->findnodes('entry');
   my $title = $entry->findvalue('title');
   printf("%s: [%s] [%s]\n", "LibXML", $title, substr($title, 0, 1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  As a result of your answer and a few experiments, a missing piece of the perl-character set jigsaw fell into place for me and I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Latin-1 is Perl's default encoding, in particular for strings in the source code. `raw` encoding is for binary data like images or videos. If you read data as raw data, it has no encoding. If you concatenate a string, which has an encoding, with the raw data, which has no encoding, Perl must guess an encoding for the raw data. Don't treat strings as raw data. And if you still want to, tell Perl the encoding, before you append the raw data to strings.

Comment: That's true, but the pod for LibXML [link](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) says explicitly

`... the functions related to I/O operations (i.e. parsing and saving) operate with binary data (in the original document encoding) obeying the encoding declaration of the XML documents....

Do NOT apply any encoding-related PerlIO layers (:utf8 or :encoding(...)) to file handles that are an input for the parses or an output for a serializer of (full) XML documents. ... ` 
`